# Social icons ignoring inline block

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created three social icons to sit next to each other on one row (see my working JSFiddle - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sdcnu40n/)).

However when I put them live on my Wordpress blog, rather than sit side by side they sit on top of each other see - https://www.moneynest.co.uk/testing-social-icons/.

How can I get my Wordpress version to mimic my JSFiddle version?

HTML

```
<div data-sumome-share="Facebook" data-sumome-share-text="Great article by the Money Nest team." class="social-icons" id="facebook_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/facebook-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align" >share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div><!--
--><div data-sumome-share="Twitter" data-sumome-share-text="Great article, check it out..." class="social-icons" id="twitter_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/twitter-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align">share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div><!--
--><div data-sumome-share="Linkedin" data-sumome-share-text="Great article, check it out..." class="social-icons" id="linkedin_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/linkedin-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align">share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div>
```

CSS

```
social-image-align {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
height: 20px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#facebook_icon {
      background-color: #3B5997;
}

#facebook_icon:hover {
  background-color: #4264a9;
}

#twitter_icon {
      background-color: #1bb2e9;
}

#twitter_icon:hover {
  background-color: #32baeb;
  }

#linkedin_icon {
      background-color: #008cd0;
}

#linkedin_icon:hover {
  background-color: #007bb6;
}

.social-icons {
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: You can use Developer Tools to see what's going on.  There are some extra `<p>` elements that are forcing the line breaks.  Removing the comments between the `<div>`'s will probably fix this.

Comment: There is some p after the divs...

Comment: https://snag.gy/w9m1aC.jpg

Comment: What does the image mean @GiacomoPaita ? Tim Barnett - I've not added any <p> tags unless Wordpress has thrown them in? My code above is exactly what I put in the page.

Comment: Wordpress adds the extra <p> tag every new line...

Comment: @SamJefferies I've added one possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @TimBarnett I had commented out between each div as a way to remove the slight space - after removing this it also removed the extra <p> tag you mentioned solving the problem. Unfortunately I am now left with the small space between each social icon. I've given your answer an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress seems to be adding some paragraph tags between your `<div>`'s

If you can't remove them, set their `display` to `none` like this.

```css
.entry-content p{
 display: none;
}

.social-icons {
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
 <div data-sumome-share="Facebook" data-sumome-share-text="Great article by the Money Nest team." class="social-icons" id="facebook_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/facebook-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align" >share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div><p><!--
 --></p><div data-sumome-share="Twitter" data-sumome-share-text="Great article, check it out..." class="social-icons" id="twitter_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/twitter-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align">share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div><p><!--
 --></p><div data-sumome-share="Linkedin" data-sumome-share-text="Great article, check it out..." class="social-icons" id="linkedin_icon"><img src="https://www.moneynest.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/linkedin-white.png" height="20px" class="social-image-align">share<span data-sumome-share-count="share"></span></div>
</div>
```